# curl(28) : ssl connection timeout

Tags: curl, wget, ssl, https, links

I try to tell only the details

My browsers have no problem with https sites. But when they get to tools like links, wget and curl, they run into trouble, sites like gitlab, github, google, etc. are unable to provide https protocol with the mentioned tools. But most sites work and have no problems.

I think the problem is with the proxy because I created a file /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh and set my proxies to listen on the ssh server socket on port 6000 but I removed it again but the problem still There was.
I even removed curl and mistakenly wiped the kernel and system with it and loaded the os live and fixed it and now it works fine but I don't have access to sites like github.com and gitlab.com (only on tools, not in the browser)

```
[ahmadreza@ahmadreza ~]$ wget https://github.com
--2022-10-08 15:13:44--  https://github.com/
Loaded CA certificate '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 140.82.121.4
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|140.82.121.4|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.

[ahmadreza@ahmadreza ~]$ curl -v https://github.com
*   Trying 140.82.121.4:443...
* Connected to github.com (140.82.121.4) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSL connection timeout
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) SSL connection timeout
[ahmadreza@ahmadreza ~]$
```

I tested this problem on centos7 and successful operation

Proxy problem or something else? If you need more documents, tell me and I will upload the article.
I used Google Translate. I apologize if my words were vague or inappropriate :)

os : archlinux

**EDIT:**
Is it possible that there is a problem with the certificate?
Because there is no reason why sites like github.com should not come up, but a site like stackoverflow should come up!!!
If so, how can I fix it?

Comment: I would suggest there is some  transparent proxy in the way and some sites are just blocked by it. Either you have a different explicit proxy set in the browser or the transparent proxy also include the TLS fingerprint into the decision of what to block. Too much unknown about your environment though, i.e. if this some corporate proxy, something an ISP does as ordered by the government etc

Comment: I live in Iran, as if the government has filtered the sites and other countries have banned us :)

Dr. Ahmadreza: A man is someone who fights sanctions and filters in Iran xD
@Steffen Ullrich

Comment: So in this case what you see is likely due to selective domain blocking by the government. I don't know though why it should work with the browser unless you have configured some proxy or so in the browser to bypass blocking - while not having the same configured for curl etc. The blocking does not seem to be DNS based but using Deep Packet Inspection - i.e. the initial TCP handshake works but then it looks into the TLS Client Hello and finds out which domain you connect to - and then blocks it.

Comment: If there was a certificate problem, I'd expect it to tell you so. Nevertheless, you could try using `curl -k` to ignore certificate issues, if only to rule it out.